# How to get the IP address of caller from Azure API Management and Application Insights

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

Our infrastructure consists of a `Azure HTTP triggers` which receive client REST calls via `Azure API Management Service`.

We use `Application Insights` for logging all throughout. However, the `client_IP` field always comes up as `0.0.0.0`. The following example is a screen capture from the `Requests` table of `Application Insights` which has been filtered on the `clould_RoleName` to show requests that have been captured by `API Management`.

[image]

What are we missing?

Thank you,

Sau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default IP addresses are temporarily collected, but not stored in Application Insights. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=net#default-behavior) for more details.

And to store the real IP addresses, you can easily follow [this documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=net#portal) to add a key/value pair `"DisableIpMasking": "true"` in your application insights resource -> arm template.

Comment: To complete, I found this tutorial useful https://piotr.gg/dev-ops/azure/collecting-ip-addresses-in-azure-app-insights.html